# Como indicar um máximo de dígitos em uma var no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, api

Estou com um código JavaScript de uma API de onde estou recebendo um número com bastante dígitos depois do ponto:

```
39.576911261669586
```

Eu queria atribuir esse número à uma variável mostrando apenas 4 dígitos, desta forma:

```
39.57
```

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, use `.toFixed()` para isso:

```
numero = 39.576911261669586; // poderia ser também numero = "39.576911261669586";
numero = Number(numero).toFixed(2); // irá retornar 39.58
```

> A vantagem de usar `Number()` é que, não importa o tipo que vier a
>   informação (do tipo *número* ou *string*), vai ser convertida em
>   *número* para ser usado no `.toFixed()` (`.toFixed()` não é compatível com strings). Em vez de `Number()`, pode-se usar também `parseFloat()`.

**Nota:** `.toFixed(2)` irá arredondar o segundo dígito para maior caso o número subsequente do original (neste caso, o terceiro dígito após o ponto) for igual ou maior que 5.

```js
numero = 39.576911261669586; // poderia ser também numero = "39.576911261669586";
numero = Number(numero).toFixed(2);
console.log(numero); // irá retornar 39.58
```

Se você quiser pegar exatamente o valor (sem arredondar), você pode fazer assim:

```
numero = "39.576911261669586";  // poderia ser também: numero = 39.576911261669586;
numero_decimais = (numero-Math.floor(numero)).toString();
numero_decimais = numero_decimais.substring(1,4);
numero = Math.floor(numero)+numero_decimais;
console.log(numero); // irá retornar 39.57
```

```js
numero = "39.576911261669586"; // poderia ser também: numero = 39.576911261669586;
numero_decimais = (numero-Math.floor(numero)).toString();
numero_decimais = numero_decimais.substring(1,4);
numero = Math.floor(numero)+numero_decimais;
 console.log(numero); // irá retornar 39.57
```

Comment: `Math.floor` não era mais fácil para apanhar só a parte inteira ?

Comment: @Isac Verdade. Já alterei a resposta. ObG!

Answer (score 2):

```js
var num = 39.576911261669586;
console.log (num.toPrecision(4));
```

> O método `toPrecision ()` formata um número com um comprimento especificado (incluindo os digitos à esquerda e à direita do ponto decimal) que deve ser exibido.

[image: suporte navegador]

Answer (score 0):

voce pode fazer assim:

```
parseFloat('39.576911261669586').toFixed(2)
```